# Live Streaming using Red5 with Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder 3.2

Tags: php, jwplayer, red5, live-streaming

Thanks in Advance
this is my first project where i suppose to do live streaming so i have decided to use red5 live streaming with Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder

i have rtmp url and also Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder installed and connected with the rtmp server.

i have written the following just for testing that it is working or not..but it is not working..

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer.js'></script>

 <div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
 'jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
 'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/player.swf',
 'file': 'livestream.flv',
 'streamer': 'rtmp://70.38.1.234:1935/celebritysecrets',
 'controlbar': 'bottom',
 'width': '470',
 'height': '290'
  });
</script>
```

but nothing is displayed ... please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **`RTMP`** URL is not working. Try testing your **`RTMP`** URL here in this [link](http://www.ideaweb.it/eng/player.cfm).

Comment: i have tested ..and it is not working...what may be the possible error or problem....like i have done something wrong whith adobe live encoder..or it is server fault

Comment: Yeah maybe server configuration. Definitely not with the encoder.

Comment: You can also use the JW Player Wizard to check these out - http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/wizard/

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any questions.